# Edit and save php.ini over terminal

Tags: php, ubuntu, configuration, server

I have set up a ubuntu 14.04. Server.

I would like edit the `php.ini` (`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`).

I can edit it with the console but how can i save it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Nano editor:**

sudo nano /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

**To save** Ctrl+x -> y -> Enter (after editing to save)

**Vim editor:**

sudo vim /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

**To save** :wq -> Enter

if you use another editor say me.

Comment: Ok, and where type i the :wg? At the end?

Comment: If you are currently in insert or append mode, press Esc key and then write  :wq

Comment: Ok, i editit over the terminal in mac osx and when i type .wg and press enter i became this error: E492: Not an editor command: wg

Comment: **:wq** ->it's Q no G and no forget the colon **:**

Answer (score 2):

Use the existing editor of ubuntu core `nano`:

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

**Note:** For the current last stable version of `PHP` (8.0) use this:

```
sudo nano /etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini
```

- Enter your sudo user password if asked from you.
- Edit your file and use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for saving the file.
- After that use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> for closing the file.

For seeing the changes, you have to restart your webserver.

if you are using `Apache`:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Or, if you are using `Nginx`:

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't run your command in root mode. Please try edit with `sudo`.

Also you can try my most favourite option: edit with `mcedit` - it will be installed with command: `sudo apt-get install mc`. Then you simply need to type: `sudo mcedit /etc/php5/cli/php.ini`. After making changes, press F2 - on the bottom of the screen you have options.